# creating a .net async wrapper to a sync request

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, async-await

I have the following situation (or a basic misunderstanding with the async await mechanism).

Assume you have a set of 1-20 web request call that takes a long time: `findItemsByProduct()`.
you want to wrap it around in an async request, that would be able to abstract all these calls into one async call, but I can't seem to be able to do it without using more threads.

If I'm doing:

```
 int total = result.paginationOutput.totalPages;
 for (int i = 2; i < total + 1; i++)
     {

      await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
         result = client.findItemsByProduct(i);
      });
      newList.AddRange(result.searchResult.item);

      }
     }
 return newList;
```

problem here, that the calls don't run together, rather they are waiting one by one. 
I would like all the calls to run together and than harvest the results.

as pseudo code, I would like the code to run like this:

```
forEach item {
  result = item.makeWebRequest();
}
foreach item {
  List.addRange(item.harvestResults);
}
```

I have no idea how to make the code to do that though..

Comment: Where did you get the idea of using `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: Does your data-access component have any asynchronous methods you could use to implement `findItemsByProduct` asynchronously?

Comment: If you want to run multiple operations at the same time (concurrently) you're really asking how to run them **in parallel**, a different (though complementary) idea to asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements which I see as:

- Process *n* number of non-blocking tasks
- Process results *after* all queries have returned

I would use the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) for this e.g.

```
var results = new ConcurrentBag<ItemType>(result.pagination.totalPages);
using (var e = new CountdownEvent(result.pagination.totalPages))
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= result.pagination.totalPages+1; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => return client.findItemsByProduct(i))
                    .ContinueWith(items => {
                        results.AddRange(items);
                        e.Signal(); // signal task is done
                    });
    }
    // Wait for all requests to complete
    e.Wait();
}
// Process results
foreach (var item in results) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer for those that can't use the async and await language features.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should add a `findItemsByProductAsync` that returns a `Task<Item[]>`. That way, you don't have to create unnecessary tasks using `StartNew` or `Task.Run`.

Then your code can look like this:

```
int total = result.paginationOutput.totalPages;

// Start all downloads; each download is represented by a task.
Task<Item[]>[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(2, total - 1)
    .Select(i => client.findItemsByProductAsync(i)).ToArray();

// Wait for all downloads to complete.
Item[][] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Flatten the results into a single collection.
return results.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem is solved easily enough without even using `await`.  Simply create each of the tasks, put all of the tasks into a list, and then use `WhenAll` on that list to get a task that represents the completion of all of those tasks:

```
public static Task<Item[]> Foo()
{
    int total = result.paginationOutput.totalPages;

    var tasks = new List<Task<Item>>();

    for (int i = 2; i < total + 1; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.findItemsByProduct(i)));
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Also note you have a major problem in how you use `result` in your code.  You're having each of the different tasks all using the same variable, so there are race conditions as to whether or not it works properly.  You could end up adding the same call twice and having one skipped entirely.  Instead you should have the call to `findItemsByProduct` be the result of the task, and use that task's `Result`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use async-await properly you have to declare your functions async, and the functions that call you also have to be async. This continues until you have once synchronous function that starts the async process.

Your function would look like this:

> by the way you didn't describe what's in the list. I assume they are
>   object of type T. in that case result.SearchResult.Item returns
>   IEnumerable

```
private async Task<List<T>> FindItems(...)
{
    int total = result.paginationOutput.totalPages;
    var newList = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 2; i < total + 1; i++)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return client.findItemsByProduct(i);
        });
        newList.AddRange(result.searchResult.item);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

If you do it this way, your function will be asynchronous, but the findItemsByProduct will be executed one after another. If you want to execute them simultaneously you should not await for the result, but start the next task before the previous one is finished. Once all tasks are started wait until all are finished. Like this:

```
private async Task<List<T>> FindItems(...)
{
    int total = result.paginationOutput.totalPages;
    var tasks= new List<Task<IEnumerable<T>>>();

    // start all tasks. don't wait for the result yet
    for (int i = 2; i < total + 1; i++)
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return client.findItemsByProduct(i);
        });
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    // now that all tasks are started, wait until all are finished
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // the result of each task is now in task.Result
    // the type of result is IEnumerable<T>
    // put all into one big list using some linq:
    return tasks.SelectMany ( task => task.Result.SearchResult.Item)
        .ToList();
    // if you're not familiar to linq yet, use a foreach:
    var newList = new List<T>();
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        newList.AddRange(task.Result.searchResult.item);
    }
    return newList;
}
```